# Modern Warfare 3 gamemode glitch

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Something strange has happened a few times to me. When playing COD Modern Warfare 3 multiplayer (on the PC), I would go to Find Match -> Standard playlists -> Team Deathmatch.
Most of the times it would work correctly, but sometimes I would get sent into a game of Domination or Drop Zone. When I am in such match, if I press Esc, the "pause" screen title would say
`"Team Deathmatch"`

but the description would say
`"Capture and defend the flags. First team to 200 wins."` (as seen [here](https://imgur.com/0nAjk32))

And no, my game is not pirated.

What is this and why is it happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(This is one of the reasons for your problem. There might be others.)

This could be a cheater lobby. Those guys can make a real mess out of the game. I strongly advise to not stay in such lobbies as they can as well mess up your personal ranking.
You can identify those lobbies usually by some turning around:

- You get incredibly high score (not always)
- There are more players than allowed in such game modes (this is most common)
- The game mode doesn't match (not always)
- (Someone has 60-0 kills and doesn't even walk around)

Other than that you should try to [re-validate your game files](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335). It could as well be a simple error in the localization files.